# Java writing to file misbehaving

Tags: java, bufferedimage, bufferedwriter

This is yet another of my Java questions.

Please take a look at this code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  if( args.length != 5) {
   System.out.println("Error. Wrong number of params!");
   System.exit(0);
  }
  File file = new File(args[0]);
  try {
   BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(file);
   FileWriter fstream = new FileWriter("output.txt");
         BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(fstream);
   int avg = 0;
      int w = image.getWidth();
      int h = image.getHeight();
      Rectangle r = new Rectangle();
      double whiteHelp = Double.parseDouble(args[4]);
      avg = (int) (avg / 1);
      int startX = Integer.parseInt(args[2]);
      int startY = Integer.parseInt(args[3]);
      r.width = r.height = Integer.parseInt(args[1]);
      for(int i = startY; i <= h - r.height; i += r.height) {
       for(int j = startX; j <= w - r.width; j += r.width) {
        r.x = j;
        r.y = i;
        avg = getTileColor(r, image, whiteHelp);
        //System.out.print(avg);
        out.write(avg);
       }
       //System.out.println();
       out.write("\n");
      }
      out.close();

      image.flush();
      System.out.println("Finished parsing the image. Solving...");
  } catch (Exception e) {
   System.out.println("Error.");
   e.printStackTrace();  
  }

 }
```

In output.txt I only get non-readable text, as if opening binary file for example.

Is there some king of problem when BufferedImage and BufferedWriter being instantiated simultaneously? I'm using the same procedure to write to file in another class, where one file is opened for reading, and another is opened for writing, and things work just fine.

p.s. How to enter &lt character without breaking the code??? Do I need to enter it as & lt ;?

Thanks

Comment: For code, please use the "code format" button in the formatting toolbar (the "0101" icon). I took the liberty of doing that for you.

Comment: btw. those System.out.print calls are showing the right thing in output when uncommented.

Comment: thank you sleske, i'm afraid I overwrote your edits, because I was back editing. I usually use PRE and CODE together. Is that a bad thing?

Comment: What does the method 'getTitleColor(...)' return? It is that you write to file. And what is the statement 'avg = (int) (avg / 1);'
 for? Dividing an integer by 1 is not so useful :-).

Comment: heheh =) it's returning the average color of a rectangle of pixels from an image, translated to 0, 1 or 2 (related to the task I'm solving). And thanks for the tip :-) that part was different, and was useful some time ago :), but then I forgot to comment it out

Comment: @playcat: The recommended way to format code is to use the code button. I've never tried using PRE+CODE, and your question was not correctly formatted, so I guess PRE+CODE does not work...

Comment: @sleske: thx... I was discouraged on using those buttons when I saw what 'blockQuote' button does. It looked wrong to me and I decided to do some handywork when posting code. I will accept a good advice though :)

Comment: @playcat: Well, "blockQuote" is not the right thing for code, it's for block quotes ;-). The main advantage of the "code" button is that you get syntax highlighting.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You invoke

```
out.write(avg)
```

to write the int avg to the output.

This will invoke the method `BufferedWriter.write(int)`; this will write out the character with the Unicode code point `avg`. This is probably not what you want ;-).

To print the number `avg` in decimal format, use

```
out.write(String.valueOf(avg))
```